# Angular4 - Typescript - Birthday Validation (Day, Month, Year)

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to implement Birthday in angular user register:
[Custom Birthday picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Dpp.png)

So, I use three fields(day, month, year). I want to insert only if the day field has a valid value related to the month (ex.: 28/february and not 31/february).
How can I do that in angular typescript?

Also, what would be best to store the birthday in database, the three columns or concatenate in one column?

Ps.: I'm not using a native datepicker because for birthday it would not be very nice and a little hard to use.

Very thanks.

Code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="cadastraPessoa()" ngNativeValidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo" formControlName="nomecompleto" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" formControlName="email" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome de usuário" formControlName="nomeusuario" required>
  </div>


  <div>
    <label>Data de Nascimento</label>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="margin-right: 0px; padding-right:1px;">
        <input style="margin-right: 0px;" type="text" minlength="2" maxlength="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Dia" formControlName="dianasc" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="margin: 0px;">
        <select name="mesnasc" formControlName="mesnasc" style="margin-right: 0px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Mês" required>
              <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Mês</option>
              <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
              <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
              <option value="3">Março</option>
              <option value="4">Abril</option>
              <option value="5">Maio</option>
              <option value="6">Junho</option>
              <option value="7">Julho</option>
              <option value="8">Agosto</option>
              <option value="9">Setembro</option>
              <option value="10">Outubro</option>
              <option value="11">Novembro</option>
              <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="margin: 0px; padding-left:1px;">
        <input style="margin-right: 0px;" type="text" aria-invalid minlength="4" maxlength="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Ano" formControlName="anonasc" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" id="senha" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" formControlName="senha" [formGroup]="formulario">


  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confsenha" name="confsenha" placeholder="Confirmação de Senha" formControlName="confsenha" [formGroup]="formulario">
    <small *ngIf="!formulario.controls.confsenha.valid || !formulario.controls.confsenha.dirty || (formulario.controls.confsenha.pristine && !formulario.submitted)" class="text-danger">
          Password mismatch
        </small>

  </div>




  <button type="submit" id="submit" [ngClass]="{disabled : !isValid}" [disabled]="!isValid" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Cadastrar</button>
  <app-alert></app-alert>
</form>
```

Comment: please add code to post

Comment: please add the code to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) which can be used to do the date validation that you are looking to do. Look at their documentation for typescript, it pretty easy.

```
npm install moment
```

in the typescript file

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

now,

```
var date = moment("2016-10-19");
```

date.isValid() tells you whether the date is valid or not.

Comment: I ended up using this way, Mr. 
Very thanks! Tremendous Help!
(const datanasc = moment('2018-01-15',       'YYYY-MM-DD', true);

Comment: @DValdirMartins - thank you. if you feel that this answer helped you please accept it as an answer.

Comment: @DValdirMartins Can you please provide your complete solution to this issue? I am having the same problem with Birthday form validation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Artyom, I posted the validation code. It worked for me this way. You can put it on a *.directive.ts file (directive) or insert inside the *.ts file of the component itself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here the validation code. Thank you!

```
static ValidDate(AC: AbstractControl) {

const birthday = AC.get('birthday').value; // to get value in input tag
const birthMonth = AC.get('birthMonth').value; // to get value in input tag
const birthYear = AC.get('birthYear').value; // to get value in input tag
const fullDate = birthYear + '-' + birthMonth + '-' + birthday;

const fullDate = moment(concatDate,       'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
 moment.locale('pt-BR');

if ( birthday !== '' && birthMonth !== '' && birthYear !== '' ) {

  if (fullDate.isValid() ) {
    AC.get('birthday').setErrors( null);
    return null;
  } else {
    AC.get('birthday').setErrors( {invalidDate: true} );
  }
}
}
```